# How to query multiple conditions or results of anonymous functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I have a form with several input fields and some Bootstrap-Buttons. Now, what I want to do is to check, if two conditions ("Are all input fields filled?" ; "Is at least one Button pushed down?") are fullfilled to enable the user to click the submit button.

This is my code:

```
function checkInput() {
    var inputFields = $("input[name=inp1],[name=inp2],[name=inp3]");
    var buttons = $("button[name=btn1],[name=btn2],[name=btn3]");
    var empty1;
    var empty2;

    buttons.click(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            empty1 = false;
        } else {
            empty1 = true;
        }
    });

    inputFields.keyup(function() {
        inputFields.each(function() {
        if($(this).val().length == 0) {
                empty2 = true;
            } else {
                empty2 = false;
            }
        });
    });

    alert(empty1);
    alert(empty2);

    if(empty1 == true && empty2 == true) {
        $('button[name=submitBtn]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('button[name=submitBtn]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

The `alert(...)` functions say, that `empty1` and `empty2` are "undifined", which i can understand. But my question is, how can I retrieve the `true` or `false` values from `buttons.click()` and `inputFields.keyup()` to query them afterwards?

Comment: The issue is that your `if (empty1 && empty2)` is running before any click/keyup has taken place. You need to move this to the inside of your event handlers or group all of this into a function where they share the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scope of the variables, those vars need to be global:

```
var empty1;
var empty2;

function checkInput() {
    var inputFields = $("input[name=inp1],[name=inp2],[name=inp3]");
    var buttons = $("button[name=btn1],[name=btn2],[name=btn3]");


    buttons.click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            empty1 = false;
        } else {
            empty1 = true;
        }
    });

    inputFields.keyup(function () {
        inputFields.each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                empty2 = true;
            } else {
                empty2 = false;
            }
        });
    });

    alert(empty1);
    alert(empty2);

    if (empty1 == true && empty2 == true) {
        $('button[name=submitBtn]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('button[name=submitBtn]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Move it outside of the function an it will works:
see it in [jsFiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xkqceLh0/9/)